# Crear JLabel por cada columna de una BD

Tags: java, array, java-swing, jdbc, jlabel

Tengo la siguiente interfaz en un programa que sirve para trabajar con una base de datos.

[image: Interfaz del programa]

Quería saber si hay alguna forma de que las JLabel Dni, nombre, apellido1... se creen de forma automática por cada columna de la tabla Clientes.

He probado con Maps y Arrays pero no he llegado a nada y el código no tiene sentido.
También he leído que en Java no se pueden crear variables de forma dinámica, con lo cual estoy bastante perdido.
¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende bien. No se si quieres cambiar el texto del label en función de los datos que quieres mostrar, o qué. Publica código y no imágenes y concreta sobre el código tu pregunta. Sino es difícil contestarte algo que te sea útil.

Comment: Disculpa. El problema es que el código que tenía lo he borrado y tampoco tenía sentido.
La idea sería crear un objeto de tipo JLabel por cada una de las columnas de la tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: `JLabel label = new JLabel( "Tu texto");` Y eso tantas veces como columnas y después muestras la ventana, frame, diágolo o lo que sea que estés creando. Lo dicho. Sin código, tu pregunta es demasiado general.

Comment: Eso sí, sería crearlo de forma manual, el problema es al hacerlo con un bucle que me declare tantas variables de tipo JLabel como columnas existan en la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Almacena en un array de string las columnas `String columns [] = {"Nombre", "Apellido"};` ,
luego crea un array de JLabel `JLabel columnsJLabels [] = new JLabel[columns.lenght()]`,
recorre el array de columnas en bucle for

```
String columns [] = {"Nombre", "Apellido"};
JLabel columnsJLabels [] = new JLabel[columns.lenght()]; //Opcional para futuras modificaciones

for(int i=0; i< columns.length();i++){
      JLabel label = new JLabel(columns[i]);
      // Alguna modificación como el tipo de letra
      // O agregarlo a la tabla
      this.JTable.add(label);

      columnsJLabels[i] = label; //Guardarlo en el array para futuras modificaciones 
}
```

y esto lo puedes ejecutar dentro de un método para llamarlo cuantas veces lo desees.

```
public void createJLabelFromColumnNames(String [] columns){
      for(int i=0; i< columns.length();i++){
      JLabel label = new JLabel(columns[i]);
      // Alguna modificación como el tipo de letra
      // O agregarlo a la tabla
      this.JTable.add(label);
      }

}
```